# Best way to cover a long video with music

Tags: editing, music

I would like to edit a long (~10 min) video made out of drone footage. I intended to cover the whole video with background music but I would also like it to mantain the same "feel" all the way through. My question is, what is the best way to cover a long video with music such that the viewer doesn't give too much attention that the music has changed? 
Or is it a better idea to use the same song and extend it or loop over and over? 
Or maybe incorporate multiple tracks with different intensities and interleave them based on the current scene? (not even sure how that would be possible, it just popped into my mind :)

Answer (score 1):

For the most part this is a stylistic choice. While I won't say it's impossible to maintain the viewers attention throughout a 10 minute Video with no narration - it's not an easy task either. I would highly recommend cutting in some B-roll and talking over it maybe, if only for a few seconds to break up the flow a bit.

However, for finding coherent music that fits the feel, I'd recommend you check out Artlist. You can filter by mood, theme, instruments, genre, etc. to find similar yet high quality music.